# Multiple definition error in C++ even when I've not included multiple files

Tags: c++, queue, iostream

I was doing the queue implementation in array. And I've just included `iostream` and no other file. My code is this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE=10;

static int front=-1;
static int rear=-1;

void ENQUEUE(int *list, int x) {
 if ((front==0 && rear==SIZE-1)||
      (front==rear+1)) {
       exit(0); //list is full
  }

  if (rear==SIZE-1) {
    rear=0;
  }
  else{
    rear=rear+1;
  }

  *(list+rear)=x;
}

int DEQUEUE(int *list){
  if (front==rear) {
    exit(0);
  }

  int x= *(list+front);
 if (front==SIZE-1) {
    front=0;
    return x;
  }
  else{
    front=front+1;
    return x;
  }
}

void viewlist(int list[]) {
  std::cout << "\n{ " << ' ';
  for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
     std::cout << list[i] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << "}" << '\n';
}

int main() {
  int list[SIZE];
  ENQUEUE(list,1);
  ENQUEUE(list, 2);
  ENQUEUE(list, 3);
  ENQUEUE(list, 4);
  viewlist(list);



  return 0;
}
```

and I'm getting this message:

---

```
g++ queue_array.cpp queue_array.cpp -o queue_array
/tmp/ccAvLHD3.o: In function `ENQUEUE(int*, int)':
queue_array.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `ENQUEUE(int*, int)'
/tmp/ccaLsRyT.o:queue_array.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccAvLHD3.o: In function `DEQUEUE(int*)':
queue_array.cpp:(.text+0x86): multiple definition of `DEQUEUE(int*)'
/tmp/ccaLsRyT.o:queue_array.cpp:(.text+0x86): first defined here
/tmp/ccAvLHD3.o: In function `viewlist(int*)':
queue_array.cpp:(.text+0xf6): multiple definition of `viewlist(int*)'
/tmp/ccaLsRyT.o:queue_array.cpp:(.text+0xf6): first defined here
/tmp/ccAvLHD3.o: In function `main':
queue_array.cpp:(.text+0x18b): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccaLsRyT.o:queue_array.cpp:(.text+0x18b): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And now I don't have any clue to what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your command:

```
g++ queue_array.cpp queue_array.cpp -o queue_array
```

You have `queue_array.cpp` in there twice, so it's being processed twice. The second time `ENQUEUE` and `DEQUEUE` are already defined from the first time it's being processed, which is why you get the error. Change it to

```
g++ queue_array.cpp -o queue_array
```

Comment: Wow!  This was such a silly mistake. I was almost locked. Thanks a lot..

Comment: No problem, It happens to the best of us. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
g++ queue_array.cpp queue_array.cpp -o queue_array
```

Why do you compile queue_array.cpp two times?

```
g++ queue_array.cpp -o queue_array
```

is enough.

Comment: That's my mistake. It was not intended.